# Are these functions equivalent in binding kthreads to a specific core?

Tags: c, multithreading, kernel, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to bind a kernel thread to a specific CPU core.

I wonder if `kthread_create_on_cpu()` ***+*** `wake_up_process()` has the same effect as `kthread_run(...)` ***+*** `kthread_bind()` on a kernel thread to set its affinity to a specific CPU core?

***P.S.:*** `wake_up_process()` is being called because the `kthread_create_on_cpu()` will put the thread on sleep state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

`kthread_create_on_cpu()` **+** `wake_up_process()` will create a `kthread` on the specified cpu, and will wake the thread up, however, `kthread_create_on_cpu()` is not exported by the kernel, so only the `kthread_create()` is available (exported). Because of that, the `kthread_bind()` is required if you want to bind a kthread to a specific core.

The combination `kthread_run()` **+** `kthread_bind()` does not work because to use `kthread_bind()` the thread **must** be stopped, as stated in [the source code](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.1/source/kernel/kthread.c#L347).

The problem is that `kthread_run()` creates and wakes the thread up, so the thread does not meet the condition for `kthread_bind()`.